# error installing py-datatable 1.0.0 on Windows 10

Tags: datatable, py-datatable

I'm running Python 3.10.9 in a conda environment with the Windows 10 OS. I'm trying to install the py-datatable package using pip, but I'm getting an error message. The pip install command successfully downloads the tarball from an internal mirror of pypi, but fails during build.

```bash
(env_python_2022_10) C:\Users\user1>pip --version
pip 22.3.1 from C:\Users\user1\.conda\envs\env_python_2022_10\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

(env_python_2022_10) C:\Users\user1>python --version
Python 3.10.9

(env_python_2022_10) C:\Users\user1>conda --version
conda 4.8.3
```

```bash
(env_python_2022_10) C:\Users\user1>pip install datatable --user
Looking in indexes: https://artifactory/artifactory/api/pypi/frb-pypi-remote/simple
Collecting datatable
  Downloading https://artifactory/artifactory/api/pypi/frb-pypi-remote/packages/packages/04/0c/bff6497afcf95a3257c4168b95c8acab91c8ef234fe473eaf6689d582da1/datatable-1.0.0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 1.1/1.1 MB 6.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      ←[90mBuilding extension ←[1;97m_datatable←[0;90m←[m
      ←[90mBuild directory = 'build\\build'←[m
      ←[90mCreated directory 'build\\build'←[m
      ←[90mDestination directory = 'src\\datatable\\lib'←[m
      ←[90mAdded 309 source files from pattern ←[1;97msrc/core/**/*.cc←[0;90m: ['src\\core\\api.cc', 'src\\core\\buffer.cc', 'src\\core\\call_logger.cc', 'src\\core\\column.cc', 'src\\core\\column_from_arrow.cc', 'src\\core\\column_from_python.cc', 'src\\core\\cstring.cc', 'src\\core\\datatable.cc', 'src\\core\\datatablemodule.cc', 'src\\core\\encodings.cc', 'src\\core\\groupby.cc', 'src\\core\\ltype.cc', 'src\\core\\mmm.cc', 'src\\core\\options.cc', 'src\\core\\py_buffers.cc', 'src\\core\\py_encodings.cc', 'src\\core\\rowindex.cc', 'src\\core\\rowindex_array.cc', 'src\\core\\rowindex_slice.cc', 'src\\core\\set_funcs.cc', 'src\\core\\sort.cc', 'src\\core\\sort_groups.cc', 'src\\core\\sort_insert.cc', 'src\\core\\stats.cc', 'src\\core\\stype.cc', 'src\\core\\writebuf.cc', 'src\\core\\wstringcol.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\arrow_bool.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\arrow_fw.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\arrow_str.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\arrow_void.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_bool.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_date32.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_numeric.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_object.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_string.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_to_bool.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_to_date32.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_to_obj.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_to_string.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\cast_to_time64.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\column_impl.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\const.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\const_na.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\date_from_months.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\date_from_weeks.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\date_from_years.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\ifelse.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\ifelsen.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\latent.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\nafilled.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\npmasked.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\pysources.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\range.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\rbound.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\repeated.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\re_match.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\sentinel.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\sentinel_fw.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\sentinel_str.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\string_plus.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\string_slice.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\time_scaled.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\truncated.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\view.cc', 'src\\core\\column\\virtual.cc', 'src\\core\\csv\\fread.cc', 'src\\core\\csv\\reader.cc', 'src\\core\\csv\\reader_arff.cc', 'src\\core\\csv\\reader_fread.cc', 'src\\core\\csv\\toa.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\args_registry.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\eval_context.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\expr.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_astype.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_column_asarg.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_column_asattr.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_cut.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_dict.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_frame.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_func.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_func_unary.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_ifelse.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_list.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_bool.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_float.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_int.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_none.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_range.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_sliceall.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_sliceint.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_slicestr.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_string.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_literal_type.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_qcut.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_round.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fexpr_slice.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_func.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_func_binary.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_func_colset.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_func_isclose.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_func_shift.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_func_unary.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_reduce.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_reduce_binary.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_reduce_nullary.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\head_reduce_unary.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\namespace.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\py_by.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\py_join.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\py_sort.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\py_update.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\workframe.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\bimaker.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\bitwise.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr_binaryop.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__add__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__compare__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__eq__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__floordiv__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__ge__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__gt__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__le__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__lt__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__mod__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__mul__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__ne__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__pow__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__sub__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\fexpr__truediv__.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\math.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fbinary\\pyfn.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\fnary.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\rowall.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\rowany.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\rowcount.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\rowfirstlast.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\rowmean.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\rowminmax.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\rowsd.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\fnary\\rowsum.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\funary\\basic.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\funary\\exponential.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\funary\\floating.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\funary\\hyperbolic.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\funary\\pyfn.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\funary\\special.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\funary\\trigonometric.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\funary\\umaker.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\re\\fexpr_match.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\str\\fexpr_len.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\time\\fexpr_day_of_week.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\time\\fexpr_hour_min_sec.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\time\\fexpr_year_month_day.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\time\\fexpr_ymd.cc', 'src\\core\\expr\\time\\fexpr_ymdt.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\cbind.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\integrity_check.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\join.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\key.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\names.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\py_frame.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\rbind.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\repeat.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\replace.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\stats.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\to_arrow.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\to_csv.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\to_numpy.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\to_pandas.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\to_python.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\__getbuffer__.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\__getitem__.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\__init__.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\__iter__.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\__repr__.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\__sizeof__.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\repr\\html_styles.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\repr\\repr_options.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\repr\\terminal_widget.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\repr\\text_column.cc', 'src\\core\\frame\\repr\\widget.cc', 'src\\core\\jay\\open_jay.cc', 'src\\core\\jay\\save_jay.cc', 'src\\core\\lib\\hh\\date.cc', 'src\\core\\lib\\mman\\mman.cc', 'src\\core\\lib\\zlib\\adler32.cc', 'src\\core\\lib\\zlib\\crc32.cc', 'src\\core\\lib\\zlib\\deflate.cc', 'src\\core\\lib\\zlib\\trees.cc', 'src\\core\\lib\\zlib\\zutil.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\aggregate.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\column_caster.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\column_hasher.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\dt_ftrl.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\dt_ftrl_base.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\dt_linearmodel.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\dt_linearmodel_base.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\kfold.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\label_encode.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\murmurhash.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\py_ftrl.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\py_linearmodel.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\py_validator.cc', 'src\\core\\models\\utils.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\api_primitives.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\job_idle.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\job_shutdown.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\parallel_for_dynamic.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\parallel_for_ordered.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\parallel_region.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\python_lock.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\string_utils.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\thread_job.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\thread_pool.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\thread_team.cc', 'src\\core\\parallel\\thread_worker.cc', 'src\\core\\progress\\progress_bar.cc', 'src\\core\\progress\\progress_manager.cc', 'src\\core\\progress\\work.cc', 'src\\core\\progress\\_options.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\arg.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\args.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\bool.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\date.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\dict.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\float.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\int.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\iter.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\list.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\namedtuple.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\obj.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\pybuffer.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\range.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\set.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\slice.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\string.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\tuple.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\xargs.cc', 'src\\core\\python\\xobject.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\chunk_coordinates.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\constants.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\input_column.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\multisource.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\output_column.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parallel_reader.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parse_context.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\preframe.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\py_fread.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\py_read_iterator.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\source.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\thread_context.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\fread\\fread_parallel_reader.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\fread\\fread_thread_context.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\info.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\parse_bool.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\parse_date.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\parse_float.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\parse_int.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\parse_string.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\parse_time.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\parse_void.cc', 'src\\core\\read\\parsers\\ptype_iterator.cc', 'src\\core\\sort\\sorter.cc', 'src\\core\\str\\split_into_nhot.cc', 'src\\core\\tests\\test_atomic.cc', 'src\\core\\tests\\test_barrier.cc', 'src\\core\\tests\\test_parallel_for.cc', 'src\\core\\tests\\test_parallel_for_ordered.cc', 'src\\core\\tests\\test_progress.cc', 'src\\core\\tests\\test_shared_mutex.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\py_type.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\typeimpl.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\typeimpl_numeric.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_bool.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_date.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_float.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_int.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_invalid.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_object.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_string.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_time.cc', 'src\\core\\types\\type_void.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\alloc.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\exceptions.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\file.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\fuzzy_match.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\logger.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\misc.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\temporary_file.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\tests.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\wcwidth.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\terminal\\terminal.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\terminal\\terminal_stream.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\terminal\\tstring.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\terminal\\tstring_impl.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\terminal\\tstring_mixed.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\terminal\\tstring_plain.cc', 'src\\core\\utils\\terminal\\tstring_styled.cc', 'src\\core\\write\\csv_writer.cc', 'src\\core\\write\\value_writer.cc', 'src\\core\\write\\write_chronicler.cc', 'src\\core\\write\\write_manager.cc', 'src\\core\\write\\writing_context.cc']←[m
      ←[90mUsing compiler of class xbuild.compiler.Compiler←[m
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user1\.conda\envs\env_python_2022_10\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 144, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'ext' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\user1\.conda\envs\env_python_2022_10\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 351, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\user1\.conda\envs\env_python_2022_10\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 333, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\user1\.conda\envs\env_python_2022_10\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 148, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-jgq357e6\datatable_73573e53d1b445f89097ca28f54fdc8d\ci\ext.py", line 587, in build_wheel
          so_file = build_extension(cmd=("debug" if debug_wheel else "build"),
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-jgq357e6\datatable_73573e53d1b445f89097ca28f54fdc8d\ci\ext.py", line 225, in build_extension
          ext.compiler.enable_colors()
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-jgq357e6\datatable_73573e53d1b445f89097ca28f54fdc8d\ci\xbuild\compiler.py", line 274, in enable_colors
          if not self.is_msvc():
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-jgq357e6\datatable_73573e53d1b445f89097ca28f54fdc8d\ci\xbuild\compiler.py", line 91, in is_msvc
          return self.flavor == "msvc"
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-jgq357e6\datatable_73573e53d1b445f89097ca28f54fdc8d\ci\xbuild\compiler.py", line 78, in flavor
          self._detect_compiler_executable()
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-jgq357e6\datatable_73573e53d1b445f89097ca28f54fdc8d\ci\xbuild\compiler.py", line 146, in _detect_compiler_executable
          self._detect_winsdk()
        File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-jgq357e6\datatable_73573e53d1b445f89097ca28f54fdc8d\ci\xbuild\compiler.py", line 207, in _detect_winsdk
          % msvc_path)
      NameError: name 'msvc_path' is not defined
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: try installing the dev version, the comments from [here](https://github.com/h2oai/datatable/issues/3305) seem to indicate that this works with the dev version. if it still fails, kindly visit the github issues page and leave a feedback for the team